# Why does visual basic use single quote for comments?

Tags: vb.net

This seems like a poor choice since the single quote is such a common character and is hard to see when reading over code.

Was there a reason to pick this over a different sequence or less used character?

Comment: That's why it's also green, well.. depending on the IDE and configuration.

Comment: I’m not sure if the people who designed the language are here to answer this, most likely very few other people know the answer to this.

Comment: I don't understand why `'` is problematic. Since VB.NET doesn't use multiline comments, it doesn't need to differentiate between `/*` and `//` and can use a single char. Why not `'`?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I can give a couple of positive features: It's not used anywhere in the language, and it's easy to type (on a standard U.S. keyboard, it's on the home row and doesn't require a shift).  Difficulty seeing it is not particularly persuasive given that going back to the VBA days, there is syntax highlighting for comments (and the highlighting is configurable in case you don't like the default, e.g. I personally prefer to use dark red instead of green).

Comment: I suspect that this is a legacy carryover from QuickBasic/QBASIC.

Comment: I guess... "Why does the alphabet start with A...?"... Not really able to answer, but did find some good reading on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe) about it.

Comment: Darn site better than the back tick. Used by SO to format code in comments. (thank you @jmcilhinney) and MySQL as quoted identifiers. Argh! My old eyes had a devil of a time figuring them out.

Answer (score 2):

How doe we arrived to VB.NET:

```
BASIC (1964) --> QuickBasic (1985) --> Visual Basic (1991) --> VB.NET (2000s)
```

In Basic, you could insert a comment by beginning your line with `REM` (for remark)

```
REM this is a comment
```

From QuickBasic, the single-quote was introduced, but `REM` is still valid nowadays

```
REM this is a comment
' this is another comment
```

Why is it like this ? We should probably ask Bill gates and Cie about it.

An assumption would be that :

1. Double quote character was already used to surround strings in BASIC
2. Single quote character was not used for anything in BASIC
3. In Bill's mind, a quote is descriptive enough for a comment, in the sense of "*to quote someone*"